# Image clipping property titanium

Tags: image, titanium, clipping

I have an image implemented using Titanium and I wanted to know if there is any way to implement the clipping property of images in titainum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can crop an image using the [Titanium.Blob.imageAsCropped](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob-method-imageAsCropped) function.

For example:

```
// Load your image from the file system
var imagefile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, "yourimage.png");
var imageBlob = imagefile.read();
// Crop it as you like
var croppedImage = blob.imageAsCropped({x : 20, y : 20, width : 100, height : 100});

// Stick it in an image view
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : croppedImage,
    ... other attributes ...
});

// Do what you want to it...
```

Comment: I can give you an example : Consider you have continously rotating wheel with some text which is cannot be seen on the main view(view1). However, when the part of the wheel which has a text passes through another view(view2); the part of text that passes through view2 becomes visible. That is what I want to create; I'm confused on how to create something like that with blob imagecrop

Comment: That was not in your question. You only asked for how to crop / clip an image.